# Calling trivial default constructor explicitly results in extra assignment call

Tags: c++, constructor

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/g/9b7sJX)

First the problem: I have a existing struct with a default constructor which puts it to a valid state. I want a NoInit constructor that does no initializations at all. Existing code has some *initialization-during-declaration* statements for the member variables, hence the example for `struct B` where I am trying to override the *initialization-during-declaration* statements by explicitly calling the default constructor of `std::atomic`.

`std::atomic` default constructor does no initialization:

> The default constructor is trivial: no initialization takes place
>   other than zero initialization of static and thread-local objects.

So, why should calling the default constructor result in any assignment in assembly?

```
struct A {
    std::atomic<long> a;
    std::atomic<long> b;
    int c;

    A() : a{1}, b{2}, c{3} {} // This is obviously fine.
    A(DefaultInit) : a(), b(), c() {} // Should this not be similar to NoInit?
    A(NoInit) {} // This is fine. Results in no code

};
```

The second constructor `A(DefaultInit)` results in assignments of 0 to the three member variables, whereas `A(NoInit)` results in no code at all.

```
struct B {
    std::atomic<long> a{1};
    std::atomic<long> b{2};
    int c{3};

    B() {} // This is fine.
    B(NoInit) : a(), b(), c() {} // Why setting to 0? Why should it generate any assignment code at all?

};
```

In this second example, `struct B`'s `B(NoInit)` tries to explicitly call `std::atomic::atomic()` which should result in no `store/mov` instruction. But this results in assignment of 0 to all three variables!

Sure the standard does say it is undefined behavior, if so why the difference between `A(DefaultInit)` and `A(NoInit)`. I want assembly of `B(NoInit)` to be same as `A(NoInit)`.

Also, note that the resulting assembly doesn't differ for member variable `c` in both cases. This has no bearing on `std::atomic`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really "call constructors explicitly". You can only specify an initializer for an object, and a constructor call can happen as part of that. I say as part of that, because an innocuous initializer can convey more meaning than one may think. In this case:

```
B(NoInit) : a(), b(), c() {}
```

The initializer `()` means you [*value-initialize*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) every member. And value initialization entails *zero-initializing* it first (since C++11). Though the exact circumstances and conditions for when and what sort of initialization occurs are somewhat involved, you can read about them at the linked article.

In your particular case, for the `std::atomic` type, this happens:

> if `T` is a class type with a default constructor that is neither
>   user-provided nor deleted (that is, it may be a class with an
>   implicitly-defined or defaulted default constructor), the object is
>   zero-initialized and then it is default-initialized if it has a
>   non-trivial default constructor;

While for the plain `int`, it's this:

> otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

Which ultimately accounts for all three zeros you see.

---

If you want to not see zero initialization, you have as far as I can tell two options. Both would be a slight exploit of the rules for initializers:

1. Omit the initializer, which is easiest.
2. Wrap it in a type for which value-initialization calls a user provided c'tor that does nothing ([here it is working](https://godbolt.org/g/G3Jik9), but to fully support your original code would require more boiler-plate for `valueless_initialization`).

Comment: *value-initialize*? Why would a() not call `std::atomic::atomic()` since no value is passed? In fact, if a value is passed, `std::atomic::atomic(T)` would be called.

Comment: @themagicalyang - That's a formal term. It does call it, as part of the general initialization. The point being that it doesn't  "just call it", and it's by design.

Comment: Is there no way to override the initializations of a,b,c in B(NoInit) so that a nop happens?

Comment: Firstly thanks for the demo, but can you explain what you meant by "ommit the initializer"?

Comment: @themagicalyang - What your question does in `A(NoInit) {}`. Don't specify an initializer at all for `a`, `b` and `c`.